# How to get data from three models that are related to each other in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So I have this model Order which has one to many relation with ProductOrder model. And also Product model which has the same one to many relation with ProductOrder model. I can get the PorductOrder data with Product or with Order. Like this:

```
Order::with('product_orders')->get();
```

Now this is returning my orders with the associated ProductOrder data. How can I include the Products of each ProductOrder data in this collection?

Comment: sounds like this is many to many relation between products and orders. Check this resource. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make changes of function name, field name, model name as per you requirements**

**Step 1:**

In you ProductOrder Model use this function:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Product',  'id', 'product_id');
}
```

**Step 2:**

After this in you query you can use as:

```
Order::with('product_orders.products')->get();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Step 1 was done already. I just wanted to know how to write that as in your Step 2. Was not quite sure what to search for that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `ProductOrder` is just a joining table/model, is that right? If that is the case, you should change to a ManyToMany relationship to of the Products model to

```
public function orders()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Orders', 'product_order');
}
```

and the Orders to

```
public function products()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products', 'product_order');
}
```

Then you can access like

`Order::find(1)->products()->get();`

Comment: Yeah I would use this way but ProductOrder is not just a joining table in my case. It has some other properties like product price, quantity for that specific order